# Rails NoMethodError (undefined method `replies' for 52:Integer):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, oop

Trying to create a reply to a Comment I receive an error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `replies' for 52:Integer):

app/controllers/replies_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

reply form

```
<%= form_with(model: @reply, url: [Comment.find(params[:id]), @reply]) do |form| %>
```

Replies Controller - Create

```
def create

@reply = @comment.replies.create(reply_params).permit(:reply)

  respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.replies.save
    format.html {redirect_to @reply, notice: 'Reply was successfully created.'}
    format.json {render :show, status: :created, location: @reply}
  else
    format.html {render :new}
    format.json {render json: @reply.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
  end
end
end


def set_comment
   @comment = Comment.find(reply_params[:post_id]).id
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "replies", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.boolean "anonymous"
t.text "text"
t.integer "user_id"
t.integer "post_id"
t.string "title"
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :comments do
  resources :replies
end
```

What I think might be the problem is the schema.
I've seen similar examples that have t.references: comment, index: true, foreign_key:true in their reply table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get association object from id:

```
@comment = Comment.find(reply_params[:post_id]).id
```

You need an object:

```
def set_comment
   @comment = Comment.find(reply_params[:post_id])
end
```

**UPDATE**

Correct controller example:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.find(reply_params[:post_id]) #In fact, it should look like this - params[:comment_id]
  @reply = @comment.replies.new(reply_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @reply.save
      format.html { redirect_to @reply, notice: 'Reply was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reply }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @reply.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

  def reply_params
    params.require(:reply).permit(...) #Model attributes
  end
```

Comment: you are right but now I have another error NoMethodError (undefined method `save' for #<Reply::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f84e17be310>): Line : 'if @comment.replies.save'

Comment: I see. You using create method for new object, in this case you don't need save. Anyways can you show all replies controller? @comment.replies.create looks strange.

Comment: @John check answer, i added an example how controller should look like.